# Powershell Regular Expression

Tags: regex, powershell

In Powershell, how do I specify a regular expression consisting of one, two or three digits, followed by a decimal point and one or two more digits, for use in a `-match` comparison?

`[0-9][0-9]*[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*`  is the closest I can come up with, but this allows more digits than I want.  I can't find any way to limit a term to a maximum number of repetitions.

Comment: Try `\b[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,2}\b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try use the following: `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}`. The numbers within the braces denote the minimum and maximum amount of repetitions which the regex engine will match. An example is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/qB0yP3/1).

The issue with your expression is that your are using the `*`. This means 0 or more repetitions of, thus, `[0-9]*` would fit an empty string, a string with 1 digit, 2 digits, and so on.

An alternative (and closer to what you did) would be to use the `?` operator instead, which means `0` or `1` instances of, thus this: `[0-9][0-9]*[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*` would become this: `[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?\.[0-9][0-9]?`, which will match a digit followed by, optionally at most 2 more numbers, followed by a period, by a digit and optionally 1 more digit.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine.  I had to add a `$` to the end, otherwise it 'floats' and accepts any further text after the match.

Comment: @rojomoke: If you have more digits then yes. You could also use `\b` to denote the end of the word instead of `$`, which would denote the end of the line or string.